# Friendly-id not generating slug when saving as of Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I have a rails 4.1 and ruby 2.1.1 app that uses the following gem set:

```
gem 'angularjs-rails'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'rails_admin-i18n', '~> 0.0.9'
gem 'inline_svg'
gem 'daemons'
gem "delayed_job_web"
gem "autoprefixer-rails"
gem 'mobvious'
gem 'mobvious-rails'
gem 'zopim_rails'
gem 'humanizer'
gem 'meta-tags'
gem 'gretel'
gem "geocoder"
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 's3_file_field'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'will_paginate-foundation'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem "paperclip-dropbox", ">= 1.1.7"
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'capistrano-rails-collection'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'rvm1-capistrano3', require: false
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 's3_direct_upload'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "jquery-fileupload-rails"
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'haml'
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'mail_form'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'correios-cep'
gem 'devise'
gem 'capistrano3-delayed-job', '~> 1.0'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'capistrano-bundler'
gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'better_errors', group: [:development, :test]
gem "binding_of_caller" , group: [:development, :test]
gem 'devise-i18n-views'
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'foundation-icons-sass-rails'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
gem "cpf_cnpj"
gem "rails_best_practices"
group :production, :staging do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
end
gem "econfig", require: "econfig/rails"
gem 'meta_request' , group: :development
group :development, :test do
   gem 'factory_girl_rails'
   gem 'rspec-collection_matchers'
   gem 'shoulda-matchers'
   gem 'rspec-rails'
   gem 'pry-rails'
end
gem 'enumerize'
gem 'gon'
gem 'premailer-rails'
```

I have overrried the should_generate method as following:

```
def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
     new_record? || slug.nil? || slug.blank? || apelido_changed?
end
```

But when I try to save or update, slug is not being generated. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: can you put your model code in and give the schema for the table?

Comment: Are you saving from rails admin?

Comment: Did you make sure to restart your rails server and console - wherever you are making your update from - before you attempted to save your model?  You need to do that after you migrate both the friendly id migration and the migration to add the slug to your model table.  You also need to extend FriendlyID in your model and define what attribute to pull the slug from - what @PavanKatepalli asked.

Comment: Its working now. Tks. The fiels apelido was not being saved correctly. Solved this and the method now works.